# how to use scanf() to input data direct to a char pointer in a struct

Tags: struct

The following code compiles but I get an access violation at runtime.

```
typedef struct login
{
    char *name;
    char *pw;
}login;

 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    login user1, user2;
    GetUser(user1);

    printf("\nUN is %s, PW is %s", user1.name, user1.pw);

    GetUser(user2);

    printf("\nUN is %s, PW is %s", user2.name, user2.pw);

    getch();
    return 0;
}

void GetUser(login &user)
{
    char *name;
    name = (char*)malloc(20);
    printf("Enter User Name: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", name);
    user.name = name;

    printf("Enter password: ");
    user.pw = GetPassword();
    free(name);
}
```

If I change the `char *name;` to a `char[20];` in the struct, the code works fine.

I modified the above code using `malloc` but after the second call to `GetUser(user2);` `user1.name == user2.name`. `user1.pw` and `user2.pw` are as expected

Comment: You are using `reference type` in the code. But the question has `c` tag

Comment: `void GetUser(login &user)` is not valid C.

Answer (score 2):

char* does not point to anything. You need to `malloc` enough bytes to hold the input you are reading.

Comment: would  it be better practice to change the `struct` to `char name[20];` or to change the `GetUser(...)` function?